# How to allow project teams to submit work requests in ADO (Azure Devops)?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I am looking for some guidance on how to best setup Azure Devops where multiple project teams can submit work requests to my team. My team would review the work request, size it up, enter the implementation date, etc...the other teams can view status updates once my team completes sizing up the request. Those requests would then be moved into our main Board to initiate dev work.

Here is a summary of the **current** process in place:

1. Other project teams would submit an intake request through a
   sharepoint form.
2. My team would review the intake request, size it up along with any
   other necessary info.
3. My team would than open a PBI in TFS with all applicable info from
   the SharePoint intake request.
4. Complete the work and update the status to "Done" in TFS.
5. Go back to SharePoint form and update the status on the intake
   request to Complete.
6. Notify the other project team that work is complete and deployed,
   etc...

I'm looking to consolidate this process completely into ADO. My teams board should not have access to edit by other project teams. Perhaps something like a PBI can be opened by other project teams with a specific access to a limited number of State/Status options? This way my team can segregate PBI's by State (Status).

Any recommendations on the best approach to handle intake requests and consolidate everything into ADO with permissions in mind would be be appreciated! I'm open to different ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The rough approach I would take uses area paths to control visibility. Under `Project Settings` -> `Project Configuration`, `Areas` tab, ensure that two area paths exist for your team: one for work intake from other teams, one for work tracking for your team (this may already exist if your project team has already been created).

Then, edit Security for the intake area path (options drop down for each area path). Add each other project team AND your project team, with "Edit work items in this node" set to "Allow".

Then, edit Security for the work tracking area path. Add each other project team, with "Edit work items in this node" set to "Deny". Your team should have "Allow" access here.

Your workflow then becomes that external teams will contribute work items to the intake path, and your team changes the area path to your work tracking area when it's time to prioritize and work them. External teams should be able to see the board, but not make modifications at this point.